# Find failed images and videos in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a long web page that includes several embedded images and videos from external sites.

If I embed the images like this `<img src="https://path-to-image.jpeg" alt="*ERROR*">`, and some of them fail to load, I can search for "*ERROR*" in the browser to find the problematic images.  I can also style the text message using CSS to be visually prominent.

For example: [image: *ERROR*] (right-click on the word to verify that it is indeed an <img> element)

This unfortunately does not work for some sites that redirect URLs that point to removed images.  Specifically, for imgur.

For example, `<img src="https://i.imgur.com/missing.jpg" alt="*ERROR*">` will display this:

[image: *ERROR*] (which is a redirect to https://i.imgur.com/removed.png)

Likewise, if a video embedded as `<video><source src="https://path-to-video.mp4"></video>` is not found, it will display something like this:

[image]

How can I replace (or overlay) such redirected images or missing videos with text elements
(that can be searched for in the browser) using HTML/CSS/Javascript?  Preferably without relying on external libraries like jQuery.

Please note that I am not very familiar with Javascript and DOM so details will be very much appreciated!

Comment: There is no catch-them all situations. For imgur, you could try to `fetch()` the resource and check in the Response object if it has been `.redirected` to `https://i.imgur.com/removed.png` (`resp.redirected && resp.url === removedURL`), but that would obviously only work with imgur, other services will need other handlers, some services may even redirect all the requests, even valid ones. As for the video case, an `error` event will be dispatched on the `<video>` element when it fails to load all resources.

Comment: I am quite OK with hand-tailored solutions.  The problem is that my knowledge of DOM and JS is practically nonexistent.

Comment: Well the problem is that we as SO answerer can't really provide hand-tailored solutions like that. Even if you did a list of all the cases that you do face, this would end up being useful only to you, since someone in the future might have some X case they'll face that you didn't. So maybe the best would be to ask one question per case, but I fear that's a bit much. Quite sorry I can't help more here.

Comment: Those "replacement" images have known characteristics, for example size, dimensions, etc.  A short example of a JS script that goes over the images in a document, and replaces those that fit a predefined criteria with text would be useful to others as well.